# How custom can I get URLs in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a page "Menu" @ /menu. I have a custom post type "Menu items," which have categories. I would like to set Wordpress up to handle URLs as such for a page, categories, and Menu items:

/menu - just the page

/menu/category - show all items in category

/menu/category/menu-item - show single menu item

Is there a way to do this? Should I be using a custom taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

Try in the admin panel under Settings/Permalinks you can change urls there..
here's the codes
http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

hope this helps, otherwise try asking here..

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should download a permalink plugin manager so you can create url based on categories, menu-items and such.

Here's a link to one : 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-permalinks/

Comment: I installed this plugin but can't do anything with it. I go to Settings > Permalinks and it's the same as before.